# Hibernate JPA delete entity with cascade (deleted entity passed to persist)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have searched for and read/studied almost every link on the web concerning problems with deleting parent entities and having the delete cascade through my OneToMany collections.  I have tried many of the suggestions, including removing all references to the contained collection, different Cascade type combinations, etc.  Still when I try to delete a parent entity, I continually get an exception on persisting a deleted entity.

I have an Adhesive entity class which contains a OneToMany relationship with AdhesiveChemicals like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Adhesive")
@NamedQueries({
public class Adhesive implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider  using these annotations to enforce field validation
    private Long adhesiveId;
    private String adhesiveName;
    private String costPerDryPound;
    private String solidPercent;
    private String totalActCost;
    private String totalDry;
    private String totalWet;
    private Boolean inactive;
    private List<AdhesiveChemicals> adhesiveChemicals;
    private List<AdhesiveComponent> adhesiveComponentsList;

    @OneToMany(cascade= {CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy="adhesive", targetEntity=AdhesiveChemicals.class, orphanRemoval=true)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<AdhesiveChemicals> getAdhesiveChemicalsList() {
        return adhesiveChemicals;
    }

    public void setAdhesiveChemicalsList(List<AdhesiveChemicals> adhesiveChemicals) {
        this.adhesiveChemicals = adhesiveChemicals;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="adhesive", targetEntity=AdhesiveComponent.class)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public List<AdhesiveComponent> getAdhesiveComponentsList() {
        return adhesiveComponentsList;
    }

    public void setAdhesiveComponentsList(List<AdhesiveComponent> adhesiveComponentsList) {
        this.adhesiveComponentsList = adhesiveComponentsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (adhesiveId != null ? adhesiveId.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Adhesive)) {
            return false;
        }
        Adhesive other = (Adhesive) object;
        if ((this.adhesiveId == null && other.adhesiveId != null) || (this.adhesiveId != null && !this.adhesiveId.equals(other.adhesiveId))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Adhesive{" + "adhesiveId=" + adhesiveId + ", adhesiveName=" + adhesiveName +
                ", costPerDryPound=" + costPerDryPound + ", solidPercent=" + solidPercent +
                ", totalActCost=" + totalActCost + ", totalDry=" + totalDry + ", totalWet=" +
                totalWet + ", inactive=" + inactive + '}';
    }

}
```

The AdhesiveChemicals class:

```
@Entity
public class AdhesiveChemicals implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Long id;
private String wetLbs;
private String dryLbs;
private String actualCost;
private Adhesive adhesive;
private Chemical chemical;

@ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="adhesive_id")
public Adhesive getAdhesive() {
    return adhesive;
}

public void setAdhesive(Adhesive adhesive) {
    this.adhesive = adhesive;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="chemical_id")
public Chemical getChemical() {
    return chemical;
}

public void setChemical(Chemical chemical) {
    this.chemical = chemical;
}



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof AdhesiveChemicals)) {
        return false;
    }
    AdhesiveChemicals other = (AdhesiveChemicals) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AdhesiveChemicals{" + "wetLbs=" + wetLbs + ", dryLbs=" + dryLbs
        + ", actualCost=" + actualCost + ", adhesive=" + adhesive + ", chemical=" + chemical + '}';
}
```

The code that is called to delete the Adhesive is here:

```
    // Handler for Button[fx:id="pricingAdhesiveDeleteButton"] onMouseClicked
public void doAdhesiveDelete(MouseEvent event) {
    // handle the event here
    logger.info("Entering {}.doAdhesiveDelete.", this.getClass().getName());
    if (pricingAdhesiveTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
        return;
    }
    DialogFX dialog = new DialogFX(DialogFX.Type.QUESTION);
    dialog.setTitleText("Delete?");
    dialog.setMessage("  Do you really wish to delete " + tempAdhesive.getAdhesive() + "?   ");
    if (dialog.showDialog() == 1) {
        return;
    }
    tempAdhesive.getAdhesiveChemicalsList().clear();
    pricingAdhesiveTableList.remove(tempAdhesive);
//        for (AdhesiveChemicals adhesiveChemicals : acList) {
//            costingService.removeAdhesiveChemicals(adhesiveChemicals.getId());
//        }
    costingService.removeAdhesive(tempAdhesive.getId());
    init();
    pricingAdhesiveDeleteButton.setDisable(true);
}
```

The costingService is a Glassfish service which has implementations of all of the create/update/delete methods on the database.  The removeAdhesive method looks like this:

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class CostingServiceImpl implements CostingService {
private static final Logger logger =      LoggerFactory.getLogger(CostingServiceImpl.class.getName());
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext(name="LamtecVoyagerPU")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.em = entityManager;
}

    @Override
public void removeAdhesive(Long Id) {
    logger.info("Entering {}.removeAdhesive.", this.getClass().getName());
    Adhesive a = em.find(Adhesive.class, Id);
//        a.getAdhesiveChemicalsList().clear();
    em.remove(a);
}
```

As you can see, at this point I have cascading limited to REFRESH, MERGE and REMOVE on the one to many relationship and I have orphan removal set to true.  However, when I try to delete an adhesive which contains some AdhesiveChemicals, the following exception is thrown.  (There is some extra stuff in there that has to do with the communication between the client and the server.)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1440)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3113)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8600(Scene.java:3051)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3333)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3119)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1559)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2261)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:228)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$2$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1435)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1012)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy463.removeAdhesive(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.invoke(RemoteInvocationTraceInterceptor.java:77)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy464.removeAdhesive(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocation.invoke(RemoteInvocation.java:205)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.invoke(DefaultRemoteInvocationExecutor.java:38)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invoke(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:78)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.invokeAndCreateResult(RemoteInvocationBasedExporter.java:114)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerServiceExporter.handleRequest(HttpInvokerServiceExporter.java:73)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:49)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationUtils.fillInClientStackTraceIfPossible(RemoteInvocationUtils.java:47)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationResult.recreate(RemoteInvocationResult.java:115)
at org.springframework.remoting.support.RemoteInvocationBasedAccessor.recreateRemoteInvocationResult(RemoteInvocationBasedAccessor.java:85)
at org.springframework.remoting.httpinvoker.HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.invoke(HttpInvokerClientInterceptor.java:148)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy14.removeAdhesive(Unknown Source)
at com.lamtec.pricingclient.PricingPresenter.doAdhesiveDelete(PricingPresenter.java:982)
... 36 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:473)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:208)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
... 102 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: deleted entity passed to persist: [com.lamtec.lamteccommon.data.costing.AdhesiveChemicals#<null>]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1369)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1315)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1321)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$3.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.CallbackCoordinator.beforeCompletion(CallbackCoordinator.java:122)
at org.hibernate.transaction.synchronization.HibernateSynchronizationImpl.beforeCompletion(HibernateSynchronizationImpl.java:51)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
... 105 more
```

The original query which populates the list containing Adhesives (and by default due to eager fetching, the AdhesiveChemicals):

```
    @Override
public List<Adhesive> listAdhesives() {
    logger.info("Entering {}.listAdhesives.", this.getClass().getName());
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Adhesive.findAll");
    List<Adhesive> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        result = query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info("Not able to get Adhesive list");
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;

}
```

The results of this are placed in the pricingAdhesiveTableList.  When I try to remove the adhesive to be deleted, I remove it from the pricingAdhesiveTableList also, as can be seen in the doAdhesiveDelete code above.

Please don't worry about my feelings.  I have already beaten myself up pretty good over this one.  I have many other deletes that are working fine, but this one continues to perplex me.  If you need any more information, please let me know.
Oh, the database is MS SQL Server and I'm using Hibernate 3.6 for my JPA provider.  Glassfish is version 3.X.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you simplify your test case by removing the unnecessary properties, getters, setters ... and give us the last queries executed before the exception is thrown ?

Comment: Done.  Let me know if you need more.  Thanks.

Comment: I need some help here.  Anyone?